# Can SOAP fault contain a header?

Tags: web-services, soap

Can SOAP fault contain a header?   I was reading that it was optional (not 100% sure) and you may have to do it manually.  Is that correct?

Comment: This question is a little vague. Are you talking about PHP's SoapFault class?

Comment: It's language not specific.   But if you're asking, I'm using Java (JAX-WS)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why SOAP fault message couldn't have headers. From transport perspective, fault is just another type of message with some specific body, headers are stored in different part of the document. I am not sure whether SOAP specification says something about this.